# Cannot open file after export as excel using PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel-1.8.0

[image]

When i download and open file excel using phpexcel

Comment: How about sharing your code and error message with us?

Answer (score 0):

Just to write ob_clean() before phpExcel save function

For Example

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'excel5');
ob_clean();
$objWriter->save("abcd.xls");
```